# Find's cost-based optimiser breaks short-circuit evaluation

Tags: gnu-findutils

Quoting the man page of find (GNU findutils 4.7.0, emphasis mine):

> GNU find searches the directory tree rooted at each given starting-point by evaluating the given expression **from left to right**, according to the rules of precedence (see section PERATORS), **until the outcome is known** (**the left hand side is false for *and* operations**, true for *or*), at which point find moves on to the next file name.

Therefore when `find` evaluates `<expr1> -and <expr2>` I would expect that `<expr2>` is not evaluated unless `<expr1>` is true and I rely on that to avoid some error messages, specifically, I do not want `find` to test whether a non readable directory is empty. Here is a [SCCCE](http://www.sscce.org):

```
mkdir some_dir
chmod 333 some_dir
find * -readable ! -empty -printf "yes" -or -printf "no" -prune
```

which yields

```
find: ‘some_dir’: Permission denied
no
```

Adding, otherwise implicit, `-and` and parentheses, the expression evaluated by `find` *should be* equivalent to

```
( ( -readable -and (! -empty ) ) -and -printf "yes" ) -or ( -printf "no" -and -prune )
```

Hence, after realising that `some_directory` is not readable, `find` should forgo the emptiness test and the evaluation of `-printf "yes"`. Instead, it should jump to the evaluation of `-printf "no"` and finally `-prune`. The "Permission denied" in the output suggests it's evaluating `-empty` anyway. (Removing `! -empty` from the original expression makes the error go away.)

Using `-D tree` to inspect the evaluation tree, I see that the optimised form (edited here for the sake of brevity and clarity) is:

```
(  (  ( ! -empty ) -and -readable ) -and -printf "yes" ) -or ( -printf "no" -and -prune )
```

according to which `-empty` is indeed evaluated and, worse, prior to `-readable` which completely screws up the intended logic. I reckon this is a bug. **Am I right?**

**Update**: (26-May-2020) A [bug report](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?58427) has been submitted and it has been confirmed as a bug by the developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, this is a bug in findutils' "arm-swapping" optimization, because it fails to consider that `-empty` and `-xtype` may have the side effect of causing `find` to report an error and exit with a non-zero status.  I've [reported](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?51926#comment5) the same issue about `-xtype`, which the findutils devs agreed was a bug.  It's hard to work around this bug too, because findutils doesn't have a way to turn off this optimization.  `-O0` is equivalent to `-O1` which already applies it.

If you need a workaround, I wrote a drop-in replacement for `find` called `bfs`: https://github.com/tavianator/bfs.  It's fully compatible with all of GNU find's options, and doesn't have this bug.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for confirming my understanding. I also wanted to disable the optimiser but, as you said, this is not possible. My expression is actually more complex than the one in my post and by writing it in another way, I've managed to trick the optimiser and the outcome is what I expect. Of course, a proper fix would be better.